# floating two div whereas one contains dynamic text - how to keep it from staying on the right of the first div?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Here is the html:

```
<div style="width:300px;height:220px;background:#00A;float:left">block 1</div>

<div style="background:#0A0;display:table-row">block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2 block 2</div>

<div style="background:#A00;display:table-row">block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3 block 3</div>

<div style="background:#600;display:table-row">block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4 block 4</div>
```

I got block 2 to appear on the right of block 1, however the problem  is when block 2 or block 3 will pass block 1's height, it will not take the full width of the page.

Here is a good example of what I want: http://sovietrussia.org/o/

How can I achieve the same layout without using tables? Basically there is a block on the left (the image) and then all other blocks appear on the right or bottom of the image depending if it fits there and the text blocks always take up 100% width

Comment: If you dont set widths to block 2 and 3 they will always take all the avaiable space which will be more than the width set on the 1st div of 300px. So in essence you div 2 and 3 will not have room above and to the right side of div 1. Floated elements should have a defined width set

Comment: How can I achieve a similar structure then without using tables?

Comment: You're trying to keep it from staying on the right?  So.. where should it be?  I think your question might need rephrased - it's very confusing, unless I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: Here I found a good example: http://sovietrussia.org/o/
How can I achieve the same layout without using tables? Basically there is a block on the left (the image) and then all other blocks appear on the right or bottom of the image depending if it fits there and the text blocks always take up 100% width

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div
{
display: table-cell;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNuSs/)

Comment: Hi, I tried the table-cell and block3 appears on the left of block2, however block2 is on the right of block1 like I wanted- so I tried `display:table-row` and it got block 3 on the bottom of block 2. Now my only problem is that when another block passed block 1 it does not take up 100% width of the page. Check out edited code in the main post

Comment: Sorry do you want block 1 to be where it is on the left, block 2 to the right side of block 1 and block 3 to be below block 1 & 2. If yes just add div#three{display: block;} - http://jsfiddle.net/uVr4g/

Comment: I want block 1 to always be where it is on the left. All the other blocks will appear either on the right or below block 1 (depending if the block passed block 1's height). So block 2 would be on the right of block 1. Block 3 would be either on the right of block 1, or on the bottom of block 1 depending if it will fit under block 2 or not.